# Frequency response of MEMS sensor in datasheet

Tags: sensor, frequency-response, mems

I am looking for a MEMS acceleration sensor and the frequency range of 0 to 20 Hz is required. But after checking a lot of datasheets I am confused. Because in most datasheets I am unable to find any info related to frequency response characteristics. But at the same time acceleration (g) ratings appear in the first place.

Shall it be calculated out of the relation between frequency and acceleration?

[KX112-1042-SR](http://kionixfs.kionix.com/en/datasheet/KX112-1042-Specifications-Rev-6.0.pdf)

Comment: Bandwidth is often the only frequency characteristic provided. If you are luck you will get a response curve but usually not. Are you the seismograph guy?

Comment: So the spec sheets include the resonant frequency?  If so, that can be used to compute the upper frequency limit.

Comment: I'm not a seismographer. I am just an hobbyist so far. I want to measure the oscillations of a building, which is below 1 Hz range.

Answer (score 1):

The -3 dB bandwidth is right there in Table 1 on page 6. What more do you need?

Comment: This doesn't explicitly state the low end, which is likely why they are confused. We can infer from the market they are made for that it goes to 0 but in another question here in the last week someone tried to dubiously argue that MEMS sensors aren't sensitive at low frequency.

Comment: I want to make sure that the sensor is able to measure below 1 Hz frequencies. E.g. for [this sensor](http://www.modalshop.com/filelibrary/3701G3FA3G.pdf) it is clearly stated it can measure from 0 up to 100 Hz frequencies. Or you can check [this one](https://www.colibrys.com/product/vs1000-vibration-sensor/).

Comment: Have you found any sensor that CAN'T read down to 0 Hz? Why would you think that this one cannot? It's implicit in the technology.

Comment: Because it is rare in general. I found some sensors but they cost way above 500 USD per sensor (links in my previous comment). But there are a lot which can measure above couple of Hz. For cheaper sensors I can not find that kind of information specified in datasheet.

Comment: Why do you say "rare in general"? You haven't given any examples, and I can't think of any. Indeed, one of the most common uses of MEMS accelerometers is to sense the direction of gravity, which for all practical purposes is "DC". As I said, it's implicit in the technology -- a constant acceleration produces a constant displacement of the proof mass, which is measured directly, usually by measuring the capacitance of interdigitated metal fingers.

Comment: Measuring DC is easy. But if you start to measure an oscillations it will become non-linear. Maybe you have right. But I have make it sure. :)

Comment: Non-linear in what sense? I'm not following your meaning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96255/discussion-between-stardust-and-dave-tweed).